# Accepting answers

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, answers, notifications

Should I every time notify a user that asks some question for which he/she gets the right(as I might think) answer from me, so that he/she will be more or less forced to accept my answer?

P.S. That could have been a nice method of forcing people to accept answers they think are right for their question by reducing their *reputation* every, say day or week, but when this person eventually accepts the answer, then all his lost point will come back to him.

P.P.S. More accepted answers, less confusion for the nomads that search for help and discovers a bunch of different answers for the question that might look similar to one bothering them.

Comment: To be honest, I _hate_ it when people will solicit extra attention when commenting on a question to say, "look at my answer," _especially_ if they mention upvoting the question.  That first of all just creates noise, doesn't give the same amount of attention to all the other answers that are on the question (you know, the people who doesn't do this), and creates a "tit-for-tat" situation where the asker feels obligated to upvote and/or accept since the answerer upvoted.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question you're asking in the first paragraph, but regarding the P.S. and the P.P.S., punishing people for not accepting answers and having more answers marked as accepted are not necessarily good things.

You want *good* and *correct* answers accepted.  If someone loses reputation for not accepting an answer, that will encourage them to just accept any answer, even if it is a bad answer.

That result would not help people searching on the site for help.  It will instead increase the amount of bad information that is (incorrectly) marked as good information.

People already have a percentage of accepted answers associated with their account and displayed to other users.  That seems like plenty of motivation to accept answers, without being overly encouraging of the acceptance of answers just for the sake of accepting an answer.

Answer (score 8):

No, you should not notify users via comments or by any other means that you've answered their question.  They're already notified when their question is answered.  They're the judge of whether the answer is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I generally dislike "please accept" comments; except every one of us has had a first day here and learned about accepting answers at *some* point, I *do* occasionally give out the [How does accepting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5235/157556) link if the user seems new enough to not know The Ways of Our People.